# Socket-io-client recieving repeated duplicate data on event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sockets, socket.io

Why am i getting multiple data received from socket-io event ?

This is client side (react)

```
//intialized socket-io-client//

socket.connect();

socket.on("recieve-message", (incomingMessage) => {
  console.log(incomingMessage);
  >! setInbox is useState setter function.
  setInbox((prev) => [...prev, { message: incomingMessage.message, fromSelf: false }])
});
```

Client side logs:https://imgcdn.dev/i/ZDVUT

On server (express js)

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.send(`Hello ${socket.id}`);
  console.log("new user connected", socket.id);

  socket.on("send-message", (data) => {
   console.log("new message recieved", data);
   io.emit("recieve-message", data);
   console.log("message sent to client");
 });
});
```

server logs:https://i.stack.imgur.com/f66sv.png

I am getting multiple messages on client side . What am i missing here?